# Python a function that takes a list of lists and converts it to a dictionary with specific format

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
[ ["He", "Helium", 2],   ["O", "Oxygen", 8],   ["N", "Nitrogen", 7] ]
```

Should turn into:

```
{ "He": ["Helium", 2],   "O": ["Oxygen", 8],   "N": ["Nitrogen", 7] }
```

my code:

```
def listToDictionary(l):
    d = {}
    for list in l:
        key = list[0]
        print key + ": "  + str(d[key][0]) + " " + str(d[key][1])
```

Answer (score 1):

In python 2:

```
dict((s[0], s[1:]) for s in lst)
# {'He': ['Helium', 2], 'N': ['Nitrogen', 7], 'O': ['Oxygen', 8]}
```

In python 3, you can use dictionary comprehension:

```
{s[0]: s[1:] for s in lst}
# {'He': ['Helium', 2], 'N': ['Nitrogen', 7], 'O': ['Oxygen', 8]}
```